# ObservableCollection not updating. What did I do wrong?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got a problem with ObservableCollection in my Xamarin.Forms App.
I am able to add values (I can read them out in the Debugger), but the view wont update.
I've tried quite a lot so far, but nothing seems to solve this problem. 
Hope you can help:)
Here's my code:

```
private ObservableCollection<Transaction> transactions = new ObservableCollection<Transaction>();
public ObservableCollection<Transaction> Transactions
    {
        get { return transactions; }
        set
        {
            transactions = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
public class Transaction:BaseViewModel
{
    private string name = null;
    private string price = null;
    private double numPrice = 0;
    private string date = null;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
            name = value;
        }
    }
    public string Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
        set
        {
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
            price = value;
        }
    }
    public double NumPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return numPrice;
        }
        set
        {
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
            numPrice = value;
        }
    }
    public string DateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return date;
        }
        set
        {
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
            date = value;
        }
    }
}
```

My BaseViewModel:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    
    protected BaseViewModel()
    {

    }

    #region Events
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    protected void OnNotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(memberName));
        }
    }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<ScrollView>
        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Transactions}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="#4D4D4D" CornerRadius="10">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding DateTime}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Price}" FontSize="20"
                                   HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance

Edit:
That's how I update the collection:

```
public void AddTransaction(string name, double price, DateTime dateTime)
    {
        Transactions.Add(new Transaction()
        {
            Name = name,
            Price = ($"-{price}€".Replace('.',',')),
            NumPrice = price,
            DateTime = dateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
        });

    }
```

Comment: Where do you update the Collection? Without this information, it will be difficult to tell what's wrong. What exactly isn't working? One thing that's definitely wrong is calling `OnPropertyChanged` before changing the value. It must come after setting the value.

Comment: One question, why are you using a BindableLayout in attached to a StackLayout instead of a ListView?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the relevant code in your snippets, but my guess is that you are replacing the entire collection instead of updating it. Remove the getter from the `Transactions` property and make sure the member `transactions` is read-only. The "Observable" relates to the *contents* of the collection, not the instance itself.

Comment: Here, the setter of the Collection raises a PropertyChanged event, so replacing the collection should work. It may be an issue with the BindableLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following and see if it works:

```xml
<ScrollView>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Transactions}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="#4D4D4D" CornerRadius="10">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding DateTime}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Price}" FontSize="20"
                                   HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollView>
```

You could also substitute the *ListView* from my example with a *CollectionView* if it meets your needs better.

**Important**

Don't forget to change the order in all of your property setters, e.g.:

```cs
public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if(name == value) return;
            name = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

**Alternative**

Another thing you can do to make sure that your views get updated is calling `OnNotifyPropertyChanged()` on the collection when adding an item:

```cs
public void AddTransaction(string name, double price, DateTime dateTime)
    {
        Transactions.Add(new Transaction()
        {
            Name = name,
            Price = ($"-{price}€".Replace('.',',')),
            NumPrice = price,
            DateTime = dateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
        });
        OnNotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Transactions));
    }
```

Technically, this shouldn't be necessary on an ObservableCollection, but the problem might be related to having a *BindableLayout* attached to a *StackLayout* as is the case in your example.